# Yii2 ActiveQuery join keep returns distinct values

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii2, query-builder

I have two tables as below

table halte :

```
CREATE TABLE `halte` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nama` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lat` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lng` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

table stops :

```
CREATE TABLE `stops` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_halte` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sequence` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_halte` (`id_halte`)
)
```

I also have some other tables which don't cause any problems.

Halte table has many to one relation to stop. The problem is when i try to get rows from halte table using right join to table stops, Yii only returns unique rows. Yii won't return same halte's row more once even stop table has more than one record related to same row in halte table.

Here's my code

```
$haltes = $modelHalte->find()
                    ->rightJoin('stops', 'halte.id = stops.id_halte')
                    ->where(['stops.id_rute'=>Yii::$app->request->get('rute')])
                    ->orderBy('sequence')
                    ->all();
```

I have tried `distinct(false)` but no result.
I've also check debugger and it run right query i want :

```
SELECT `halte`.* FROM `halte` RIGHT JOIN `stops` ON halte.id = stops.id_halte WHERE `stops`.`id_rute`='1' ORDER BY `sequence`
```

I tried to run that query manually and it returned 29 rows which is what what i want. But in Yii, it only returned 27 rows because 2 rows is same record in halte table.

I know i can achieve this using `yii\db\Query`, but i want to use ActiveRecord.

Are there any way to work around this?
I would really appreciate your opinion/help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check the sql command generated by you active query

```
$haltes = $modelHalte->find()
                ->rightJoin('stops', 'halte.id = stops.id_halte')
                ->where(['stops.id_rute'=>Yii::$app->request->get('rute')])
                ->orderBy('sequence')
                ->all();

 echo $haltes->createCommand()->sql;
```

or to get the SQL with all parameters included try:

```
 $haltes->createCommand()->getRawSql();
```

And compare the code generated by ActiveQuery with your created manually ..

Comment: I consider you said it without `->all()`.
It returned `SELECT 'halte'.* FROM 'halte' RIGHT JOIN 'stops' ON stops.id = stops.id_halte WHERE 'stops'.'id_rute'=:qp0 ORDER BY 'sequence'`
It still ignore the same records. When i run it manually, it returns 31 rows but yii only returns 28 rows.

Comment: What do you mean without ->all()..?  you shuold test the exact same query you perform .. with all()

Comment: It throws `Call to a member function createCommand() on a non-object` exception if i insert ->all();

Comment: ok ... i thinking to the first sample not the second .  then if the query are the same could be you have some diffrence in .qp0   vs the value you use in test (eg: a space or some not visible char)  ..

Comment: no, it's just number 1 to indicate route id. It's also id_rute=1 when i try the second sample

Comment: May I know how did you determine that you return only distinct rows?

Comment: Of course, thank you for your answer this far.
Like i said before, when i run query on Yii, it only returns different 28 records. But, when i run it manually using same query i got from yii  debugger or code you provided to me, it returns 31 rows which has 3 same rows. it's because there are some rows from stops table references same rows on halte table.